# Machine Learning_New class detection

Tags: r, algorithm, machine-learning

I have a data mining problem and would like to have your suggestion/opinion on the approach part.

It is a multi class problem, I need to build classifier and for a new data point, algorithm should be able to recognize whether the data point belongs to existing classes or it belongs to new class(C+1).

Current approach I am following is, if probability for a particular class is >60% then the record gets classified in to that class and if none of the classes have >60% probability then the record will be classified in to New class(C+1).

But the accuracy for the New class recognition is low(~30 to 40%). I have used C5.0 boosted decision tree algorithm.

95% of the features have binary data.

Could any one please suggest any other alternative approach / algorithm for this.

Sri

Comment: you may want to vary your threshold 60% and see what impact it has on accuracy.

Comment: Decision trees sound like a good option.

Comment: Is this a supervised learning problem? I.e., Are your data labeled or unlabeled?

Comment: @KotaMori- It is supervised learning problem..labels are there.

Answer (score 0):

There many supervised classification alternatives , for the case of R  one excelent option is support vector machine classification using the e1071 package. I would also suggest to try and evaluate softmax neural networks.